# For $0<b \leq a$ prove that $\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{a} \right) \leq \frac{a+b}{2}-\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{b} \right) $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

For $0<b \leq a$ prove that $$\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{a} \right) \leq \frac{a+b}{2}-\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{b} \right) $$

I was trying compare the following expressions
$$\frac{a+b}{2}-\sqrt{ab} =\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2$$

$$\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{a} \right)=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2\leq\frac{1}{a}(a-b)^2$$
and use the fact that $\sqrt{a}  \leq a$ when  $a>0$ but I don´t get good results.

Any hint of how I should start?

Comment: **Hint:**

i) $a+b - 2\sqrt{ab} = (\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2$

ii) $a-b = (\sqrt a - \sqrt b) (\sqrt a + \sqrt b)$

iii) $2\sqrt b \leq \sqrt a + \sqrt b \leq 2\sqrt a$

Comment: Why did you add the tag multivariable-calculus?

Comment: Becasue usually problems of show inequalitys have nice solution using tools of multivariable calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt a  - \sqrt b )^2  = \frac{b}{{2(\sqrt a  + \sqrt b )^2 }}\left( {\frac{{(a - b)^2 }}{b}} \right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt a  - \sqrt b )^2  = \frac{a}{{2(\sqrt a  + \sqrt b )^2 }}\left( {\frac{{(a - b)^2 }}{a}} \right).
$$
Use the fact that $0<b\leq a$ to estimate the right-hand sides from above and below.

Comment: I think that it could useful, how  do you think in this equalty?

Comment: @JuanT Are you asking about the way I got these equalities?

Comment: Yes, about the creative process for get it

Comment: $$
\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt a  - \sqrt b )^2  = \frac{1}{2}\frac{{(\sqrt a  - \sqrt b )^2 (\sqrt a  + \sqrt b )^2 }}{{(\sqrt a  + \sqrt b )^2 }} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{{\left[ {(\sqrt a  - \sqrt b )(\sqrt a  + \sqrt b )} \right]^2 }}{{(\sqrt a  + \sqrt b )^2 }} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{{(a - b)^2 }}{{(\sqrt a  + \sqrt b )^2 }} =  \cdots 
$$

Comment: great, thanks a lot, nice hint.